# Verify that the following definition of the delta function is valid

Tags: integration, dirac-delta

I want to verify that the following is a valid definition of the delta function:

$$\delta(x)=\lim_{a \to 0} \frac{1}{\pi}\frac{a}{a^2+x^2}$$

This satisfies $$\begin{cases} 0 & \text{if } x \neq 0 \\ \infty & \text{if } x=0 \end{cases}$$

I think I also need to verify that $\int_\mathbb{R} \delta(x) \, dx=1$. How do I do this?

Comment: You need to pin down the proper meaning. By definition, $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) \delta(x) dx = f(0)$ for continuous $f$. Your problem is to prove that $\lim_{a \to 0} \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) \frac{a}{\pi(a^2+x^2)} dx = f(0)$ for continuous $f$. (Note that we don't take the limit directly on the approximate delta function, but only on the integral.) This will give your normalization condition for free (take $f=1$). Deriving that limit will require you to apply the definition of continuity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$F(a) =\frac 1{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{a}{a^2+x^2} dx = \frac {1}{\pi}\arctan \frac xa |_{-\infty}^\infty = 1$

$\lim_\limits{a\to 0} F(a) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta (x)\ dx = 1$

Comment: How did you conclude that $\arctan \frac{x}{a} |_{-\infty}^{\infty}=1$?

Comment: $\arctan{\infty} = \frac {\pi}{2}$  I dropped the $\frac {1}{\pi}$ factor (now fixed)